# Creating a cumulative totals column

Tags: mysql, query

I currently have a query which calculates the `total Purchase cost`, `Total Sales Price`, `Profit` and `Mark up` per month which I then display on a graph.
The query looks like

```
SELECT SUM(SaleTotal) AS TotalSalePrice, SUM(CostTotal) AS 
TotalPurchaseCost, SUM(Profit) AS Profit, MONTHNAME(CollectionDate) AS Month, ((SUM(Profit ) / SUM(DriverTotal)) * 100) AS Markup
FROM TableA
Order BY CollectionDate
```

I want to to create another similar query which returns a `monthly cumulative result` for Total cost, Total Sale Price & Profit

So if the figures from the above query returns

| Month | Total Sale Cost | Total Purchase Cost | Profit | Markup |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| January | £200 | £100 | £100 | 100% |
| February | £400 | £300 | £100 | 33% |
| March | £300 | £175 | £125 | 71% |
| April | £500 | £380 | £120 | 32% |

I want a query which would return the following (note the 2 new columns on the end

| Month | Total Sale Cost | Total Purchase Cost | Profit | Markup | Cumulative sales price | Cumulative Profit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| January | £200 | £100 | £100 | 100% | £200 | £100 |
| February | £400 | £300 | £100 | 33% | £600 | £200 |
| March | £300 | £175 | £125 | 71% | £900 | £325 |
| April | £500 | £380 | £120 | 32% | £1400 | £445 |

Essentially adding the current months total to the total from the previous months

Can anyone help adapt the current query to include the last 2 columns

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: @mustaccio What am I to consider? Is my question not clear enough?

Comment: MySQL 8.0 is needed to get "Windowing functions", such as you need here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SUM OVER` as a cumulative window function. Note that this is calculated *after* normal aggregation, so you can do `SUM(SUM(...)) OVER (...`

```
SELECT
  MONTHNAME(LAST_DAY(CollectionDate)) AS Month,
  SUM(SaleTotal) AS TotalSalePrice,
  SUM(CostTotal) AS TotalPurchaseCost,
  SUM(Profit) AS Profit,
  (SUM(Profit) / SUM(DriverTotal)) * 100 AS Markup,
  SUM(SUM(SaleTotal)) OVER (ORDER BY LAST_DAY(CollectionDate)
      ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS CumulativeSalesPrice
  SUM(SUM(Profit)) OVER (ORDER BY LAST_DAY(CollectionDate)
      ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS CumulativeProfit
FROM TableA
GROUP BY
  LAST_DAY(CollectionDate)
ORDER BY
  LAST_DAY(CollectionDate);
```

Note the use of a proper grouping construct. Do not rely on MySQL's idiosyncratic method of displaying columsn which are not in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Thanks for that.
I actually managed to solve it using ChatGPT, the answer they gave was essentially the same as yours.